# Can't connect using ssh keys to dropbear

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, authentication, openssh

I have two pair of (same) embedded device that runs linux. I have setup the same ssh key on both. I can connect to one using that key but the 2nd machine still ask for password. Obviously I am doing it right on first machine so its working but why is it not working on the 2nd machine? My client is windows 7 machine (the one I am connecting from).

On windows: I have `.ssh\id_dsa` (private key) and corresponding config file.

I have moved public key (`id_dsa.pub` file) to both linux machines using `scp` at `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file . I make sure I do exactly the same thing both places.

I have checked on file permissions on the server (`root`, `.ssh` folders and `authorized_keys` file) and I make sure they are identical on both machines.
My question is why does the key work in one machine but doesn't seem to work the other?

I am using OpenSSH (part of MingW) on Windows 7 to connect.

Comment: same permission (`drwx----`) on `/root/.ssh` ? same configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?

Comment: @Archemar `/root/.ssh` is `drwxr-xr-x`and this is same on both units. I don't have `/etc/ssh`folder, should I create one?

Comment: directory `/root/.ssh` should be `drwx------` (that is `chmod 700 /root/.ssh` ), try this first.

Comment: @Archemar I set 700 on `/root/.ssh` and 600 on `authorized_keys`, no difference. I also than went to to do 700 on `/root` still no change.

Comment: We figured it out. the root was not owned by root on the unit, fixing that fixed everything.